# get by id in a loop method in html javascript

Tags: javascript, html

i pastly worked on python tkinter and built an app, but there are some limitations on tkinter
so moving to django web frame, but little knowlagde about javascripy huddle at,

```
<tbody>
   <tr name="bill_details">
        <td>{{bill_detail.stock.barcode}}</td>
        <td>{{bill_detail.stock.mainType}}</td>
        <td>{{bill_detail.stock.subType}}</td>
        <td id="qty">{{bill_detail.quantity}}</td>
        <td id="price">{{bill_detail.price}}</td>
        <td>product(qty, price)</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

I have by loop method placing the values in the places needed the product of the qty and price

I viewed some examples some like below

```
<script>
    function product(qty, price){
        console.log(qty *price);
        return qty * price
    }
</script>
```

is there a way to approach like this or any other method

I got like table data but not getting the quantity and price

```
    values.forEach(function(value){
        console.log(value.innerHTML.qty);
    });
```

Comment: did you try `<td>{{ bill_detail.quantity * bill_detail.price }}</td>`

Answer (score 1):

I'm having a hard time following your question.

Shouldn't it be `<td>product(bill_detail.price.quantity, bill_detail.price.price)</td>` instead of `<td>product(qty, price)</td>` ?